# how to make array with given name(string) in golang with reflect

Tags: reflection, go

I want to make array with name in golang, but I got some error
here is my code
package main

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

type My struct{
    Name string
    Id int
}

func main() {
    my := &My{}
    myType := reflect.TypeOf(my)
    fmt.Println(myType)
    //v := reflect.New(myType).Elem().Interface()

    // I want to make array  with My
    //a := make([](myType.(type),0)  //can compile
    //a := make([]v.(type),0)  ////can compile
    fmt.Println(a)
}
```

Answer (score 9):

I believe this is what you're looking for:

```
 slice := reflect.MakeSlice(reflect.SliceOf(myType), 0, 0).Interface()
```

Working example:

- http://play.golang.org/p/jiYluu52ae

As a side note, in most cases a nil slice is more suitable than one with capacity zero. If you want a nil slice, this would do instead:

```
 slice := reflect.Zero(reflect.SliceOf(myType)).Interface()
```

Comment: but how can I do append on it

Comment: You can use the `reflect.Append` and `AppendSlice` functions.

Comment: @GustavoNiemeyer So I tried your method and it looks good until I then try to send a pointer to that slice into a lib and it fries the typing: http://play.golang.org/p/13nbz6z42b (note the fact that the last two don't match.

Answer (score 5):

Note: if you want to create an actual *array* (and not a slice), you will have in Go 1.5 (August 2015) **`reflect.ArrayOf`**.

See [review 4111](https://go-review.googlesource.com/#/c/4111/) and [commit 918fdae](https://github.com/golang/go/commit/918fdae3482b203565aef4d37cee05bf1b46431d) by [Sebastien Binet (`sbinet`)](https://github.com/sbinet), fixing [a 2013 issue 5996](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/5996).

> ### `reflect`: implement `ArrayOf`
>
> This change exposes `reflect.ArrayOf` to create new `reflect.Type` array
>   types at runtime, when given a `reflect.Type` element.
>
> - `reflect`: implement `ArrayOf`
> - `reflect`: tests for `ArrayOf`
> - `runtime`: document that `typeAlg` is used by reflect and must be kept in
>     synchronized

That allows [for test like](https://github.com/golang/go/commit/918fdae3482b203565aef4d37cee05bf1b46431d#diff-906e67319cf90fa821907cea89745e49R3560):

```
at1 := ArrayOf(5, TypeOf(string("")))
at := ArrayOf(6, at1)
v1 := New(at).Elem()
v2 := New(at).Elem()

v1.Index(0).Index(0).Set(ValueOf("abc"))
v2.Index(0).Index(0).Set(ValueOf("efg"))
if i1, i2 := v1.Interface(), v2.Interface(); i1 == i2 {
    t.Errorf("constructed arrays %v and %v should not be equal", i1, i2)
}
```